# How to assign ‘author’ role to User in strapi.io?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, frontend, admin, strapi

In the user table when I am trying to assign a role to a user, it is showing public and authenticated options only. How to select ‘author’/‘editor’ or any other to the user through the admin panel and also through API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to understand that the `Editor`, `Author` & `Super Admin` are roles for **admin panel users only**. So basically, it will only control/limit what the user can do after logging in into the admin panel (`http://localhost:1337/admin`). Additionally, these roles can only be assigned to the admin panel users which can be created by visiting the following module:

`http://localhost:1337/admin/settings/users`.

Now coming to your question, as to why we can't assign `Editor`/`Author` to users in the users collection, it's because the roles assigned to these users are in a separate module:

`http://localhost:1337/admin/settings/users-permissions/roles`

The roles created in this module are basically assigned to `API` consumers. So you could create roles of your own choice in this module and then:

1. Limit the set of `API`s this role can access
2. Define whether the route will be `public` **or** `private` to this role
3. Set `rate limiting`

Once you create the roles of your choice in this module, then you can go to `users` collection module.

`http://localhost:1337/admin/plugins/content-manager/collectionType/plugins::users-permissions.user?page=1&pageSize=10&_sort=username:ASC`

You could then create users (`API` ***consumers/users***) who will have their own set of credentials (***email & password***) which can then be used for acquiring the bearer token.

###### So, to sum up, just create the roles you want to assign to users in [this](http://localhost:1337/admin/settings/users-permissions/roles) module and then use the user with that role for acquiring bearer token, following which you can call the `API`s with that token. Simple!

> **P.S**: `Bearer Token` is used on the headers for accessing private routes enabled for that particular user role.